# Log in with a password

Tags: password, users

I have not enabled auto login, but I can still log in to my account without entering my password. I want to turn this option off and let Ubuntu ask me for my password before logging in. This is only the case with one account. I believe it's the root account that has this no password option enabled I am using Ubuntu 13.10.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have zou checked if there is a password set for this account (**System Settings** > **User Accounts**)?

Comment: Yes. Also, when I open Chrome I am asked for my login key ring (=password). So I kind of have to give my password but it's not at login but when I'm opening an application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you enabled *passwordless login* (which is different from *auto-login*). This is controlled by membership of the `nopasswdlogin` group, so you should be able to disable it by removing your user from that group, e.g. using the command

```
sudo gpasswd --delete username nopasswdlogin
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I don't know how it got in that group in the first place but it's fixed now. I believe there are a lot of people having this problem, but this solution was nowhere to be found. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh by the way, I want to upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputation. Sorry!