# Not asking for password in GUI for login even when there is a password set in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, login, password, lightdm, gui

I have a user which has no sudo rights. I have set the password for the user using cli. But when I logout and try to login again, the user is not asked for a passord and logs in as soon as the username is clicked in the GUI.

Has anyone faced this issue?

Using lightdm.

As part of troubleshooting I added a new user and set its password through GUI and when I logged in again I was asked for a password. But my 1st user could still login without a password.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Possibly related: [Log in with a password](http://askubuntu.com/questions/426725/log-in-with-a-password/426752#426752)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where its located in 14.04 but if you go to Settings - Users and Groups then select the user that can login without a password and where it says Password click Change. In 16.04 there is a checkbox for `Don't ask for password on login` If that is checked .. uncheck it and that should take care of the problem